# Tomcat смена порта 8080 на 80

Tags: java, tomcat

Почему когда я в томкате в `conf/server.xml`

```
 <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

8080 меняю на 80 у меня просто вылетает ошибка

```
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Просто не следует менять порт, потому что это не просто.

Comment: @RomanC проблему уже решил, а то что вы написали - полный бред.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что, чтобы использовать порт 80 нужно иметь права администратора. До 1000 точно все порты, только для администраторских прав.

Comment: это касается только `linux`)